# multiple db reference_usage permission at once snowflake

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, share, user-permissions

I am working on a secure view and share in snowflake.
So, I need to grant reference_usage of each DB to share before granting view permission to share.

My view has like 7-8 databases in its statement(due to joining) and so I need to grant all these DB reference usage permission to share.

One way of doing this, I can run the below command for each database.

```
grant reference_usage on database db_XYZ to share share_ABC;
```

Is there any command in snowflake to grant permission to all databases at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the REFERENCE_USAGE privilege must be granted individually to each database.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege-share.html#usage-notes

Of course, you can write a script to generate and execute grant commands for all databases.